# Express - Session doesn't get saved between subsequent SSE requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, server-sent-events

I'm exploring Server-sent Events with Node.js and Express.
I managed to set up request handling and writing of the stream, but now I'm struggling with session management, because I can't get the session to be persisted between subsequent calls.

**Server code:**

```js
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

var app = express();
// log all requests
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.method, req.path);
    next();
});
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret : 'pretty hard to guess',
    resave : false,
    saveUninitialized : true
}));

// serve test file
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/sandbox/test.html');
});

app.get('/test/:name', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.headers);

    // session is empty
    console.log(req.session)

    req.session.name = req.param('name');

    // session.name is set
    console.log(req.session);

    req.socket.setTimeout(Infinity);
    res.type('text/event-stream');
    console.log(res._headers)

    res.write('retry: 3000\n');
    res.write('data: Hello, SSE!\n\n');
});

var server = app.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log('listening on port 8080\n');
});
```

**Tiny client app:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function sendReq() {
                var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
                var es = new EventSource('test/' + name);
                es.onopen = function() {
                    var ul = document.getElementById('board');
                    var li = document.createElement('li');
                    li.textContent = 'Connected...';
                    ul.appendChild(li);
                };
                es.onmessage = function(e) {
                    var ul = document.getElementById('board');
                    var li = document.createElement('li');
                    li.textContent = e.data;
                    ul.appendChild(li);
                };
                return false;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id=sse-form onsubmit="return sendReq();">
            <input id=name />
            <input type=submit />
            <ul id=board></ul>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When accessing `localhost:8080/` and sending my name once, I can see the server log the call on the console and setting the session data and cookie.

If I send my name again, the session cookie is set, but the session is empty, so the session cookie gets sent again.

How can I manage to store session data between calls?

Answer (score 0):

The `resave` handle tells the session to persist your cookie values. Otherwise you have to manually re-set them on each request.

```
app.use(session({
    secret : 'pretty hard to guess',
    resave : true, <-----
    saveUninitialized : true
}));
```

Quote from the docs https://github.com/expressjs/session:

> resave - forces session to be saved even when unmodified. (default:
>   true)

Comment: I already tried changing `resave` to `true`, but to no avail... this does not solve the issue, unfortunately. Thanks anyway!